# public Point2D midpoint()

Tags: java, computer-science

java code by the way, that includes **code from 2 different classes**

- **public** Point2D midpoint(Point2D other)

  This method creates and returns a new, distinct *Point2D* object that is the midpoint of the line segment formed by this *Point2D* object and the *Point2D* object referenced by *other*.  For example, the midpoint of points (1, 2) and (3, 4) is a new point (2, 3).  This method assumes that both the x and y coordinates of the midpoint are integers.

  ***from the Point2D class***
- **public** Point2D midpoint()

  This method returns the Point2D object that is the midpoint of this Line2D object.  This method must call the midpoint method in Point2D for the instance variables of this object, taking advantage of the operation implemented there.

  **from the line2D class**

this is the code I tried for ***the Point2D class***:

```
public Point2D midpoint(Point2D other) {
        this.x = x + other.x;
        this.y = y + other.y;
        return new Point2D(x / 2, y / 2);
```

This is the code I tried for **the line2D class:**

```
public Point2D midpoint() {
        return new Point2D((endPoint1.getX() + endPoint2.getX()) / 2, (endPoint1.getY() + endPoint2.getY()) / 2);
```

but I am not getting the results I expected

Comment: Why does `midpoint` in the `Point2D` class modify `this.x` and `this.y`? Probably should just be `return new Point((x + other.x) / 2, (y + other.y) / 2);`

Comment: Pretty much the same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77229133/public-point2d-addpoint2d-other

Answer (score 0):

You modify the this object in `midpoint()` method. It can lead to unexpected behavior. Instead, you should create a new Point2D object to represent the midpoint.

Also you don't use `midpoint()` method from the `class Point2D` in your `midpoint()` method. Instead, you calculate `midpoint` yourself. This is unnecessary, as the `class Point2D` already provides `midpoint()` method.

Updated code:

```
public Point2D midpoint(Point2D other) {
  return new Point2D((this.x + other.x) / 2, (this.y + other.y) / 2);
}

public Point2D midpoint() {
  return endPoint1.midpoint(endPoint2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use static methods. You can overload the `midpoint` method three times.

1. Takes a `Line2D` object
2. Takes 2 `Point2D` objects
3. Takes 4 `double` values i.e. `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`

```java
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class LinePointDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point2D startPoint = new Point2D.Double(0, 0),
                endPoint = new Point2D.Double(10, 20);

        System.out.printf("Midpoint: %s%n", midpoint(startPoint, endPoint)); // (5, 10)

        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(startPoint, endPoint);

        System.out.printf("Midpoint: %s%n", midpoint(line)); // (5, 10)
    }

    public static Point2D midpoint(Line2D line) {
        return midpoint(line.getP1(), line.getP2());
    }

    public static Point2D midpoint(Point2D startPoint, Point2D endPoint) {
        return midpoint(startPoint.getX(), startPoint.getY(),
                endPoint.getX(), endPoint.getY());
    }

    public static Point2D midpoint(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        return new Point2D.Double((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2);
    }
}
```

If you have a class e.g. `Player` with a position `x` and `y`, you could reuse these methods above:

```java
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Player {
    private float x;
    private float y;

    public Player(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point2D getPosition() {
        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }

    public void setPosition(Point2D point) {
        this.x = (float) point.getX();
        this.y = (float) point.getY();
    }

    public Point2D midpoint(Point2D point) {
        return midpoint(this.x, this.y, point.getX(), point.getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player(0, 0);
        Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(10, 20);
        System.out.println(player.midpoint(point)); // (5, 10)
    }

    public static Point2D midpoint(Line2D line) {
        return midpoint(line.getP1(), line.getP2());
    }

    public static Point2D midpoint(Point2D startPoint, Point2D endPoint) {
        return midpoint(startPoint.getX(), startPoint.getY(),
                endPoint.getX(), endPoint.getY());
    }

    public static Point2D midpoint(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        return new Point2D.Double((x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2);
    }
}
```